# Java: Struts2 with IntelliJ for beginners

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, struts2

I'm attempting my first Strusts2 project(Windows, 64x, ItelliJ).

I'm following the tutorial found here:

https://struts.apache.org/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-using-maven-to-manage-artifacts-and-to-build-the-application.html

This a picture of my file structure, web.xml, & struts.xml:

http://screencast.com/t/0F5LN2nR4Dt

This tutorial uses **Maven** to manage artifacts and build the web application archive (war) file.  I currently learning Maven as well, used a few times, but still pretty new.

When I built the project in **IntelliJ**, *File > New Project > Java > Web Application > Struts 2*.  This created the setup you will see in the picture above.  It appears to have added all needed files and structure to the project, with one exception, *Step 4 - Add Logging(**log4j**)*.  As far as I can tell, the IntelliJ Struts2 setup pulled in most/all of the needed ***dependencies***, except for:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

I have all the needed files, except for log4j.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c.%M:%L - %m%n"/> 
       </layout> 
    </appender>

    <!-- specify the logging level for loggers from other libraries -->
    <logger name="com.opensymphony">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.struts2">
         <level value="DEBUG" />
    </logger>

   <!-- for all other loggers log only info and above log messages -->
     <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/> 
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
     </root> 

</log4j:configuration>
```

The above tutorial states, *"Setup a log4j.xml configuration in the src/main/resources folder."*

So I guess my questions are:

1) Do I need to/should I add Maven to this project?  If so how do I go about this?

2) How should I go about bring in the log4j.jar(s), where should I place them?

3) Where in my file structure would you recommend that create my resource folder?

4) Anything else you think might help someone learning Struts2.

Comment: First of all where in this tutorials ever written that you should use an IDE like IntelliJ? Second you didn't follow or don't understand the tutorial. Third Struts2 tutorials are not for beginners, but for experienced developers, who are familiar with web development, but lacked Struts knowledge.  If you don't know how or don't want to follow the tutorial,  nobody can help with it.

Comment: "Ah, but a man's reach should exceed his grasp, Or what's a heaven for?"
-Robert Browning

Comment: SO is about as far away from heaven as you're going to get. Roman's point was that you're trying to do too much at once. Crawl before walking, and all that. Pithy quotes aside, while it's fine to learn stuff, try doing it in smaller bites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, you should probably use either Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies (it makes it way easier).

2) If you decide to use Maven, all you gotta do is put the pom.xml that the guide you are using has in the root directory of your project. [Here's the pom.](https://github.com/apache/struts-examples/blob/master/pom.xml)

3) Typically the resources folder goes in src/main (src/main/resources).

4) [Mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/struts-2-tutorials/) is a pretty good learning resource. Good luck!